# How get device resolution for loading sharp images but size fonts/divs properly with viewport width=device-width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

On mobile, if I don't use the tag (see below) to set the viewport width to device width, then fonts are too small and hard to read and divs size more like on a desktop.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But if I use that, then choosing what size image to load will return a small, pixelated image because the reported pixel width is half what it really is.  For example, an iPhone 5S will report a width of `320px` when it's really showing a resolution of `640px` wide.

How do I allow for both these differences? *(without the viewport tag, the css will not size properly. with it, my code loads too low a resolution image on devices that report 1 pixel width for every pixel on screen)*

I can't just double the pixel width when loading images because not every device/browser halves the pixel size.

I want the fonts and elements to be sized based on `width=device-width` but not the images I load. How do I combine these?

Comment: @quantumwannabe Can you please write that as an answer so I can mark this question answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `window.devicePixelRatio` and multiply it by the width that you plan to display your image at to get the real width of image that you will need.